# where condition in customer collection

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, collection, collection-filtering

I have filed 'read' in alireza_checkingout_checkingout table I want to add condition if read =0 in query below, I alreadt tried `->addFieldToFilter('read', array('eq' => 0))` but the system return an error "**fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in /var/www/html/megadump/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816**"

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')

 ->addNameToSelect()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
 ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
 ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
 ->joinTable('alireza_checkingout_checkingout','alireza_customer_id=entity_id',array('alireza_customer_id','read'),null,'left')
 ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
 ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
 ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
 ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
 ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
 $collection->getSelect()->columns('count(alireza_customer_id) as cc')->group('entity_id');
 $this->setCollection($collection);

 return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EAV models, like the customer, `addFieldToFilter` is an alias for `addAttributeToFilter` and only works if the parameter ("read" in your case) is a real EAV attribute of the customer and not a field in the `customer_entity` table, or any other table.

The error message hints that there is no attribute (`$attribute->getBackend()` fails because there was no attribute found).

But if `read` actually is a field in the entity table, you can tell the collection so, using `addStaticField()`:

```
$collection->addStaticField('read')->addFieldToFilter('read', array('eq' => 0));
```

**Update:** I see that the field actually is from a joined table. You need to use `joinAttribute` or `joinField` to allow using the field for filters.

I assume, `alireza_checkingout_checkingout` is a regular table, not an EAV entity:

#### Replace

```
->joinTable('alireza_checkingout_checkingout','alireza_customer_id=entity_id',array('alireza_customer_id','read'),null,'left')
```

#### with

```
->joinField('read', 'alireza_checkingout_checkingout', 'read', 'alireza_customer_id=entity_id')
```

You can even add the filter immediately, as `joinField` has a `$cond` parameter:

```
->joinField('read', 'alireza_checkingout_checkingout', 'read', 'alireza_customer_id=entity_id', '{table}.read=0')
```

The condition will be added to the `ON` clause of the join, which is by default an `INNER JOIN`, so the result is the same as using `addFieldToFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
$attrInstance->getBackend()
```

bellow link will help to understand.

http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/91985359245/call-to-a-member-function-getbackend-on-a

**I hope will help you.**